# In linux terminal, what is the command that'll tell me in which folder am I?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

In linux terminal, what is the command that'll tell me in which folder am I?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You are looking for `pwd`.

Comment: **P**rint **W**orking **D**irectory

Comment: @SimaWB thank you. I was having a very smooth brain moment.

Answer (score 9):

PWD(1)
       pwd - print name of current/working directory